# Where to ask for a name suggestion for my C++ class?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have two classes in my application for which I need good short names.

Should I ask my question on "Programmers"? or on "Code Review"?

Comment: Nowhere, since it will be 'primarily opinion based'.

Comment: [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6582/31260)

Comment: {underwear type=asbestos}How about asking in The Lounge?{/underwear}

Comment: <---- Loungers sending rays of hate at @MichaelT

Comment: Why was my question voted down? Should I have asked it in "The Longue"? (I wasn't quite aware of this 'chat' site till now; I'm using an old computer and wasn't sure such site will work on it).

Comment: [voting on meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) - you need to understand that to understand the votes here.  And they're more a "yea or nay" type vote that is intended as guidance rather than anything binding (and it doesn't touch your rep or anything else on the main site).  Next, chat has been a feature for awhile that you can get to from the menu: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cHFrI.png .  The Lounge is the C++ oriented room ( http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/10/loungec ) ...

Comment: ... note that the occupants of The Lounge are C++ programers most of the time and thus have a higher [curmudgeon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curmudgeon) density than other rooms.  To that extent my (bad) advice was partly making fun of them and saying "you *might* try there, but make sure you figure out how to ask questions in the room without needing to borrow my asbestos underwear for the inevitable flames..." I haven't done laundry yet.

Answer (score 13):

Neither.

Identifier names are a typical case of an opinion-based question. There's not really a good answer to it.

However, if you'd like to have your code improved for other things, that better fit the requirements of Code Review, people might suggest better names for your classes in the process.
Just don't post there if you *only* want better identifiers. Post there if your question is generally [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Code Review.